# Python: Ignore xmlns in elementtree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

Is there a way to ignore the XML namespace in tage names in `elementtree.ElementTree`?

I try to print all `technicalContact` tags:

```
for item in root.getiterator(tag='{http://www.example.com}technicalContact'):
        print item.tag, item.text
```

And I get something like:

```
{http://www.example.com}technicalContact blah@example.com
```

But what I really want is:

```
technicalContact blah@example.com
```

Is there a way to display only the suffix (sans xmlns), or better - iterate over the elements without explicitly stating xmlns?

Comment: See my answer under http://stackoverflow.com/a/25920989/2593383 for a more general solution

Comment: see also: [Python ElementTree module: How to ignore the namespace of XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412496/python-elementtree-module-how-to-ignore-the-namespace-of-xml-files-to-locate-ma/76601149#76601149)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a generator to recursively search through your element tree in order to find tags which end with the appropriate tag name. For example, something like this:

```
def get_element_by_tag(element, tag):
    if element.tag.endswith(tag):
        yield element
    for child in element:
        for g in get_element_by_tag(child, tag):
            yield g
```

This just checks for tags which end with `tag`, i.e. ignoring any leading namespace. You can then iterate over any tag you want as follows:

```
for item in get_element_by_tag(elemettree, 'technicalContact'):
    ...
```

This generator in action:

```
>>> xml_str = """<root xmlns="http://www.example.com">
... <technicalContact>Test1</technicalContact>
... <technicalContact>Test2</technicalContact>
... </root>
... """

xml_etree = etree.fromstring(xml_str)

>>> for item in get_element_by_tag(xml_etree, 'technicalContact')
...     print item.tag, item.text
... 
{http://www.example.com}technicalContact Test1
{http://www.example.com}technicalContact Test2
```

Comment: Hopefully the above answers the question. A difference I have noticed is that `item` in the generator example does not have a `next` method. Still, other than this it behaves in the same (similar?) way to `etree.getiterator`.

Answer (score 1):

I always end up by using something like

```
item.tag.split("}")[1][0:]
```

Comment: It does not address the iterator issue - I still have to iterate over the full tag name.

Comment: I am not aware of any of the different xml handlers for python that do that. With lxml you could use a xlst on the xml before you parse it.

Comment: The `[0:]` is pointless. If you are trying to get a copy of it so as not to change the original you can simply do `[:]`. Or, if that isn't a problem, just remove the `[0:]` altogether.